# Python console - inspect classes or functions defined in a particular module

Tags: python, module

If you want to see what modules are defined in a particular module while in the Python shell, one option is to type `dir(path.to.module)`. Unfortunately, this doesn't just list the classes or functions defined in a particular module, it also included classes or functions that the module imports

Comment: "this doesn't just list the classes or functions defined in a particular module, it also included classes or functions defined in a particular module" - I'm not seeing the difference. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @user2357112: Updated now. I meant to say that it includes classes that the module imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will only return functions and classes defined in a particular module

```
def getDefined(module):
    print([x for x in dir(module) if
        getattr(module.__dict__[x], '__module__','')==module.__name__
    ])
```

Comment: This can be misleading, since something can be part of a module's public API without being defined in the module. For example, `heapq.heappush.__module__ == '_heapq'`, and `numpy.array.__module__ == 'numpy.core.multiarray'`.